# Xcode code completion, search through whole method name

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there any way to have Xcode's code completion search the whole method name for the characters I start typing? For example if I start typing `[self con` I want things like `navigationController` to show up, whereas now I have to type `[self nav` to see that.

Comment: have a look at [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're currently in a file, you can click on the jump bar and start typing:

[image: jump bar]

<sub>No, that's not a leak of the official app.</sub>

**EDIT** Now I see you are talking about in-code-writing code completion. No, there isn't a way to do that - imagine how annoying it would be when you type `[self a` and every single method with an `a` in the name shows up. Wouldn't be fun.

Comment: WWDC 2013... Looks intriguing.

Comment: @Undo actually Visual Studio does just that and I miss it a lot

Comment: @Moshe I can't tell you what it is or else *they* will get me :)

Comment: @Undo - I'm sure. :-) I'm gonna start extrapolating, though. :p As soon as I see the session with 2 scroll views, I'll know what this is. (Also, have an upboat!)

Comment: @Moshe You mean session **207**?

Comment: Really, though, it's just my submission for the 2013 student scholarship. Nice job at figuring that much out from a 400x100 screenshot, though. You going to WWDC?

Comment: If I can clear my schedule and get a scholarship. I went last year - totally a blast.

Comment: @Moshe Were there lines for talks - and you couldn't get in if you weren't in line early enough?

Comment: @Moshe That's fine. I don't really need to know. Right now I need to focus on winning :)

Comment: @Tai It's all about the rep :)

Comment: @Moshe I just got an email that I won!

Comment: Congratulations sir, have a great time!

Comment: Also, glad to see you're restarting the App Stores proposal. Shame I couldn't see it through...

Answer (score 1):

The "Open Quickly" shortcut is what you're looking for.

**⇧⌘o**

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Opening_File_by_Filename_or_Symbol_Name.html